# Knockout : How to find the called methods

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

Simple question and probably already asked but, I don't get how this knockoutJs works and I can't find any clear explanations.

I'm under `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html`

```
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'} -->
            <!--ko template: { name: element.shippingMethodItemTemplate} --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
```

I would like to know where is located the method called with `rates()`. What is the way to find it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open: **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html**

Check the following line:

Now open JS component: **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js**

You can see the template declaration like:

```
shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
```

And method:

```
rates: shippingService.getShippingRates(),
```